# laptop fan not recognized by ubuntu 20.04

Tags: fan, fancontrol, sensors, lm-sensors

i ran `sudo sensors-detect` and it gave me this

```
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# System: LENOVO 81H7 [Lenovo ideapad 130-15IKB] (laptop)
# Board: LENOVO LNVNB161216
# Kernel: 5.4.0-31-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz (6/142/10)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): yes
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): yes
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): yes
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.4: Sunrise Point-LP (PCH)

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 6040 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes
Client found at address 0x52
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 Yes
    (confidence 8, not a hardware monitoring chip)

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.
Client at address 0x2c can not be probed - unload all client drivers first!

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-A (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

output of `sudo pwmconfig`

`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

i tested my laptop on windows 10 ,fan working fine and temp  most of time is 30-35
but in Ubuntu its between 45-55 
any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution, I am facing same issue on HP laptop with ubuntu 20.04.1